# How to return a xml from axis2 webservice?

Tags: java, xml, apache-axis

How to return a xml from axis2 webservice and how to add different parameter in xml in axis2?

Comment: You understand that SOAP messages are XML formatted? Revise the WSDL file for your webservice and regenerate the java code.